# How to get specific instance of class from another class in Java?

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller, class, instance

I've created the following class with the `main` method, which creates new instance of `Application` and instances of `ApplicationModel`, `ApplicationView` and `ApplicationController` for this particular `Application`.

```
public class Application
{

    // Variables

    private ApplicationSettings         settings;
    private ApplicationModel            model;
    private ApplicationView             view;
    private ApplicationController       controller;

    // Constructor

    public Application()
    {
        settings        = new ApplicationSettings();
        model           = new ApplicationModel();
        view            = new ApplicationView(model);
        controller      = new ApplicationController();
    }

    // Main method

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application application = new Application();
    }

    // Getters for settings, model, view, controller for instance of Application

}
```

I know, that there will always be only one unique instance of `Application`.

And I want to get this particular instance in my `ApplicationModel`, `ApplicationView` and `ApplicationController` classes.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use a singleton on Application class.

Put a `public static` method to return your one and only application instance.

```
public class Application
{
    private Application() { } // make your constructor private, so the only war
                              // to access "application" is through singleton pattern

    private static Application _app;

    public static Application getSharedApplication() 
    {
        if (_app == null)
            _app = new Application();
        return _app;
    }
}
```

You can read more about *singleton design pattern* [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Every time you need the one and only `Application` instance, you do:

```
Application app = Application.getSharedApplication();
```

Comment: And, probably, you made a typo. `Application _app` should be static, if it is referenced from static method. Please, correct it, as I'm not sure. :)

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits: yes! It wasn't a typo. I just forget to put the keyword in there. It **must** be **static**.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the Singleton design pattern if you need to guarantee there will only be one instance of Application and you need it to be accessible by those classes. I'm not going to comment on if it's the best way to build your application, but it will satisfy the requirements in your question.

[Singleton design pattern tutorial](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-singleton-design-pattern)

Comment: Yes, that will perfectly suit me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Change the constructor of your `Application` class to be `private` and send the `this` object to the `ApplicationXxx` classes.

```
private Application()
{
    settings        = new ApplicationSettings(this);
    model           = new ApplicationModel(this);
    view            = new ApplicationView(this, model);
    controller      = new ApplicationController(this);
}
```

You will be able to call `new` on the `Application` class from within the `main` method.

Your `ApplicationSettings`, `ApplicationModel`, `ApplicationView` and `ApplicationController` must be updated to take an `Application` object in their constructors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've been using this approach, but it wasn't what I wanted to achieve. Now I'd rather use Singleton design pattern, as proposed by Pablo Santa Cruz and smcg.

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits Just don't forget that [Singletons are evil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons).

Answer (score 1):

Add parameter of the `Application` type to the constructors of the composites. When you create their instances just pass `this`. For example

```
public class Application {
  String s = "Setting";
  class ApplicationSettings {
    Application sc;
    ApplicationSettings(Application sc){
      this.sc = sc;
      System.out.println(sc.s);
    }
  }

  // Variables

  private ApplicationSettings settings;

  // Constructor

  public Application()
  {
    settings = new ApplicationSettings(this);
  }

  // Main method

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Application application = new Application();

  }

  // Getters for settings, model, view, controller for instance of Application

}
```

Comment: I think, Singleton pattern will be better for me, because I want only one instance of my `Application`. But thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this right now, you can pass `this` as a constructor arg within the constructor of `Application` to other classes (assuming the have a reference declared for the main class). That way you can obviously make multiple instances of the `Application` class. If that is what you want...

Comment: I want to create only one instance of `Application`. Anyway, thank you for your answer.